# How to make player move in 3D space?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move my Player into 3D space. I can make it move up and down using the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class Player : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private CharacterController _controller;


        void Start()
        {
            _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        }


        void Update()
        {
            float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, verticalInput, 0);
            _controller.Move(direction * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

How can I make the Player move on z-axis?

Comment: `Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, verticalInput, **Z-Axis**);`

Comment: @FelixCastor Can you explain your code to the OP please?

Comment: Also, to the OP (Original Poster) themself, could you please specify what method you would like to use? Do you want to use the keyboard keys? Do you want to use the mouse? Are you looking to do this with a joystick? There are many ways to achieve what you are looking for so it will help us give you the desired answer if we know which method you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the `Vertical` and `Horizontal` axis to move the [CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) on the X and Z, then use another input (button or axis) to move it vertically, on the Y axis? Here's a good starting point.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player: MonoBehaviour
{
   private CharacterController cc;


   void Start()
   {
      cc = GetComponent <CharacterController>();
   }


   void Update()
   {
      float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

      Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical);

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) direction.y = 5f;

      // Simulate some kind of gravity
      direction.y -= 9.81 f * Time.deltaTime;

      cc.Move(direction * Time.deltaTime);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Putting vertical in the z-axis did wonder for me. And the code you shared worked fine. Thank you again!

Comment: Happy to be helpful. Remember to mark the question as answered.